# passing argument from controller to ActionFilterAtribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, action-filter

I'm making a project, and for the project, I need to use a session. I'm using ActionFilters to get my data from my session before my method, and put it back after my method.

Now the problem I'm having is that I'm never putting my data in my session with OnActionExecuted. I've been searching for this problem for quite some time and still haven't found it. Probably looked every single site and still nothing.

This is my action filter:

```
public class SessieFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ISessieRepository _sessieRepository;
    private string _sessieCode;

    public SessieFilter(ISessieRepository sessieRepository) {
        _sessieRepository = sessieRepository;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        //_sessie = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Sessie") == null ?
        //    new Sessie() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sessie>(context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Sessie"));
        _sessieCode = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Code") == null ?
            "" : context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Code");
        context.ActionArguments["Code"] = _sessieCode;
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
        //context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Sessie", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_sessie));
        context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Code", _sessieCode);
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }

}
```

And the code that should give my "SessieCode" to my OnActionExecuted so I can save it in a session is:

```
public IActionResult Overzicht(string Code, string SessieCode) {
        Sessie sessie = _sessieRepository.GetBy(SessieCode);
        Code = SessieCode;
        if (sessie != null)
        {
            IList<Groep> groepjes = new List<Groep>() ;
            foreach(var groep in sessie.Groepen) {

                if (!groep.NeemtDeel)
                {
                    groepjes.Add(groep);
                }
            }
            return View(groepjes);
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Through the whole Controller, I'm using the same "Sessie". So I want to save the "SessieCode" in a session so I can look up the "Sessie" via the "SessieRepository".

My actionArgument["Code"] is given to the Controller just fine, but it's not given to the OnActionExecuted, and the value "_sessieCode" in my Filter stays empty for ever.

I'd love to get some help and finaly fix this thing!

Comment: Full controller code: https://paste.ofcode.org/PfMbYRg54EG2du3Jtu8wWQ

Comment: Since `SessieCode` overwrites `Code` (the value from session state) 100% of the time in your action method, it is unclear what exactly you want to save in session state. But action filters can read both the `model` and `ViewBag` from the passed in `context` parameter.